# Identifying compile time of binary in kernel space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am writing a piece of code in kernel, which can get the time stamp of other binaries. By timestamp, I mean the time of compilation of the binary.

Is there some way to get this information?

The time stamp is available in user space when we do ls -l. So ideally it should be embedded some where in the elf file. How can i get this piece of information?

Thanks in advance.

-Gomathi

Comment: In general, avoid putting inside the kernel what can be done in userland.

Comment: **Why do you ask**? Why the compile time should matter in kernel space?

Answer (score 3):

The compilation time of a binary is not available (unless it is coded in C or C++ and use the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` predefined preprocessor macros).

AFAIK, the [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) specification does not store any timestamps by default (and if it did, it could be `strip`-ed).

What `ls -l` (and also the [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) command) gives you is some metadata (kept by the file system) given by the [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) syscall; you probably want the `st_mtime` (or `st_mtim` as a `timespec`) field, giving the last modification time of a file. But for instance, a `cp` of an ELF file would give the current time as `st_mtime` to the new copy.

But the `st_mtime` field for an ELF executable is the time the linker (or something else, like `cp`) wrote that executable (so it is more related to the link time than to the *compile* time).

To retrieve it in kernel land, look inside the kernel [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) of the executable file (in the [VFS](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lki/lki-3.html) probably)

You did not state your real goals, but I guess they can (and should) be done in user-land (look into [acct(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/acct.2.html) & [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)...). Avoid patching the kernel for such things.